# Powershell Remote path + Wildcard Question

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Could you please help me with this script? I am writing in PowerShell a script in order to monitor data of one **.csv** file into **PRTG**, basically script goes to a remote server make a SFTP connection and brings it to PRTG server.
Then I just look for the data, the issue is that I have is to select and specific file, for example in the remote server there is a new file with and specific date generated every hour and some values are without a pattern.

I already tested and script works except, to look for specific file, cause if I put static name file works

These are examples of .csv files that i need
structure is 
**`name + date (Y-m-d-H) + 8 characters +.csv`**:

```
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606021446-174.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606031630-456.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606041445-288.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606051513-761.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606061446-877.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606071446-454.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606081446-838.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606091505-171.csv
RG_400_Total_by_Hour-20210606101447-220.csv
```

This is the part where I completely stuck.
How can I use a wildcard in this variable that I'm trying:

```
$file=$remotepath+"/RG_400_Total_by_Hour-"+$date+""+$WILDCARD???+""
```

### Here is a part of the script

```
$date= get-date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H"
$t= Look for wildcart to use   
$folder=$date
$hora= [int] (get-date (get-date).addhours(-2) -UFormat "%H")
$ayer = (get-date (get-date).addDays(-1) -UFormat "%Y%m%d")
if ($hora -eq 22) {$folder=$ayer}
if ($hora -eq 23) {$folder=$ayer}
$remotepath= $remotedir
$remotedir="/usr/local/sandvine/var/nds/cache/csv"
$file=$remotepath+"/RG_400_Total_by_Hour-"+$b+""+$t+""
$file2=$localpath+"/RG_400_Total_by_Hour-"+$b+""+$t+""   
Get-SFTPFile -SFTPsession $global:Session -remotefile $file -localpath $localpath
Remove-SFTPSession -sftpsession $global:Session | Out-Null
```

I really appreciate any comment, thanks guys.

Comment: [`Get-SFTPFile`](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Get-SFTPFile.md) doesn't support wildcard parameters, so you'll probably need to find matching directories via `Get-SFTPChildItem`, which itself apparently also doesn't support them, so you'll probably have to get the children of the _parent_ directory and then filter by name.

Comment: where is `$b` coming from?

Comment: Sorry was a mistake, is not $b, is $date